# Does Chrome supports HTML5 canvas circle?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

I am trying to draw a circle on canvas. With Firefox it looks like a circle, but with Chrome it looks deformed. Here is my JavaScript code:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "brown";    
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(480,250,100, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? I have latest version of Chrome.

[image]

Comment: does this work for you on chrome? http://jsfiddle.net/87ZLX/

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? And tell us what version of Chrome you're on?

Comment: My version is 33.0.1750.149 m. Your circle also does not works for me :(

Comment: Well it works perfectly for me on Chrome, Firefox, Opera and even Internet Explorer XD Also quick question, did you get any errors in the console or something to better help us find the problem?

Comment: If you have no errors and it doesn't work for you, considering having a look at your extensions to see if they are doing anything.

Comment: I have no errors in the console, but still doesn't work... What your mean by extensions?